# Eloquent Model has parent model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, subclass

I have a Model called User with stuff like name, country and some relationships.

Now I want a Model, e.g. Vendor, having all the same functions and variables as a User including some More stuff

I thought I could to it this was:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{

    use Authenticatable; SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'last_login'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'password',
        'country',
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Log');
    }
}
```

And the Vendor Model:

```
class Vendor extends User
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'description'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'vendor_id');
    }
```

The Controller checks the role of the user and loads a user model or a vendor model:

```
if(Auth::user()->role > 1)
    $user = Vendor::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
else
    $user = Auth::user();
return $user->load('logs');
```

But the load call fails for a vendor. I was able to join the fields of a user inside a vendor but I also need the functions of it.

Comment: What is the error you're getting when trying to load the logs for a vendor?

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'logs.vendor_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `logs` where `logs`.`vendor_id` in (1)), but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the logs function checks a field that doesn't exists.
Using this functions works:

```
public function logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Log', 'user_id', get_called_class() !== get_class() ? 'user_id' : 'id');
}
```